# Add Table Row Dynamically with Materializecss

Tags: javascript, materialize

I am using **materializecss.com** `Datepicker`, see https://materializecss.com/pickers.html, and I have a table with an Add Button, which adds a new row with input fields, but it doesn't generate the Datetime Picker field to work. Duplicating the row neither works.

Am implementing something simmilar to http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/LAECx/ only problem is seems Materialize builds the DATETIME during onLoad event

Comment: You should use materialize in your project https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html and also initialize datepicker https://materializecss.com/pickers.html

Comment: @bahmanparsamanesh I have used it in my project, question is how to add it on dynamically/runtime (after page load) as opposed to binding it before page loads

Comment: Please add what you did until now to your jsfiddle example. So anyone can see what is the problem exactly.